# Move Google Data Studio reports to Workspace account

Tags: looker-studio

I am using free Gmail account for my Google Data Studio insights. I am now using Google Workspace.

How do I migrate my reports associated with my Gmail account to my new workspace account?

Answer (score 0):

Your dashboards are not "inside" your Gmail account.  They are just owned by your Gmail account.

To make them available to a new account, just share your dashboard with the new account.  Doing so, you can make the new member the owner of the dashboard (and you can even remove the access from previous user if really desired).

To add users:

- Click "Share"
- In "Add people" tab, add who you wish to view the report
- You can select if you want to allow the person to just view or edit the dashboard

To change owner:

- Click "Share"
- In "Manage access" tab, click on the combo "Can edit"/"Can view" right of the name of who you want to be the owner
- Select "Make owner"